# Extract DB name and table name from snowflake query using snowsql

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Insert into D.d
Select * from A.a join B.b on
A.a.a1=B.b.b1 
Join C.c on C.c.c1=B.b.b1
```

I have complex statements for which i need to extract  source db name ( in above statement source DB are A,B,C and source tables are a,b,c &Target Db is D and target table is d)

Need output like

SourceDB SourceTbl TargetDB Targettbl
A,B,C      a,b,c      D         d

Or we can get values in json format as well for each field.. Also this needs to accomodate for update and delete statements  as well. Please assist

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQLPARSE to parse the statement. I am providing a code below which is not optimally and efficiently written, but it has the logic to get the information

```
import sqlparse
raw = 'Insert into D.d ' \
      'Select * from A.a join B.b on ' \
      'A.a.a1=B.b.b1  Join C.c on C.c.c1=B.b.b1;'

parsed = sqlparse.parse(raw)[0]

tgt_switch = "N"
src_switch = "N"
src_table=[]
tgt_table= ""
for items in parsed.tokens:
    #print(items,items.ttype)
    if str(items)  == "into":

        tgt_switch ="Y"
    if tgt_switch == "Y" and items.ttype is None:
        tgt_switch = "N"
        tgt_table = items

    if str(items).lower() == "from" or str(items).lower() == "join":
        src_switch = "Y"
    if src_switch == "Y" and items.ttype is None:
        src_switch = "N"
        src_table.append(str(items))

target_db = str(tgt_table).split(".")[0]
target_tbl = str(tgt_table).split(".")[1]
print("Target DB is {} and Target table is {}".format(target_db,target_tbl))
for obj in src_table:
    src_db = str(obj).split(".")[0]
    src_tbl = str(obj).split(".")[1]
    print("Source DB is {} and Source table is {}".format(src_db, src_tbl))
```

Comment: Hi @Rajib Deb thanks a lot for sharing the code. I was more interested in getting this solution in SQL. Can you please let me know if the same can be solved using SQL/SNOWSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not offer any SQL statement parsing support. You can hack at it with regex'es, of course, or use any of the tools on the market.

If this query ran, and ran successfully, you can use ACCESS_HISTORY view https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html to see which tables (A.a, B.b, C.c, D.d) and columns (A.a.a1, B.b.b1, C.c.c1, D.d.d1) it accessed  and how (read or write).